# Vue Router Duplicating Routes with Name Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vite

I have Vite apps and routing using automatic routing with https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages. When I `console.log()` on the `router/index.ts` file, it shows the right routes. But when I tried to `console.log()` the routes on component with `router.getRoutes()` it shows some duplicated route with name: `undefined`.

router/index.ts

```js
console.log("Routes", newRoutes)

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(BASE_URL),
  routes: newRoutes,
})
```

[image: routes]

layouts/default.vue

```js
const router = useRouter();
console.log("Router naon", router.getRoutes());
```

[image]

I have tried looking on my Nuxtjs apps and it seems like it doesn't duplicated anything like this.  This became problem because when I tried to push router with `name`, it doesn't go to the right page.

Comment: well, vue-router doesn't do this, so it could be something wrong with vite-plugin-pages - by the way - you say it shows "some duplicated routes" ... I think you mean "all routes are duplicated" ... `15 * 2 === 30`

Comment: looks like it. I have tried on vanilla Vue Router and it doesn't duplicated anything

Comment: where do those names come from? I can't see how that plugin would create them

Comment: I added it for locale routing

Comment: how? perhaps it's your code that's caused this :p

Comment: I don't think so. Because I tried deleting my code and only did `createRouter` , it still got duplicated

Comment: Hey @panjigemilang did you ever manage to figure this out? I'm getting the same thing and can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: @GilesButler Im done using automatic routing so I made my own routing haha

Comment: Haha that's one way to do it and not a bad way to go! Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit some digging and turns out this is being caused by https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts - the plugin basically takes your routes and sets the layout as the component. It then creates a new child route with the original route. There are a few issues about this on his github ([issues/55](https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts/issues/55), [issue/92](https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts/issues/92)). I can't work out if it's the intended behaviour or not as I think the original route should really be removed and the route with the new layout and child route should replace it.